# On click first enter the method and then go to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image and a button. I have a method which will generate an image randomly from a set of images. For some reason as I click on the button apart from doing the event, it is also entering again in the method 'chooseImage' of the Image and generate another id.

Below here you can find the asp of the image and the image Button;

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="200px" OnDataBinding="chooseImage" />


<asp:ImageButton ID="aboutBtn" src="Resources/Icons/HomeAboutMeBtn.png" OnClick="AboutBtn_Click" runat="server" />
```

Below here I also posted the event handler of the button, where the childId is being generated from the 'chooseImge' method and stored in a global variable.

```
protected void AboutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ChildDescription.aspx?id=" + childId);
        }
```

Any suggestions why or how can I do it? Basically I would like to pass as a session the id of the image being displayed on load page.

Below here you can find the method. Basically first I am reading from database a set of records. Then I am storing the id in array, and then by calling a random generator method it will randomly choose an id from the array.

```
protected void chooseImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllChildren", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                array.Add(reader["Child_ID"].ToString());
                                counter++;
                            }

                      connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

                if (array.Count != 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetChildDetails", connection))
                        {
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            childId = Convert.ToInt32(array[RandomNumber(1, counter - 1)]);
                            command.Parameters.Add("@ChildID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = childId;
                            connection.Open();

                            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    Image1.ImageUrl = "Resources/Children Images/" + reader["Primary_Image"].ToString();
                                    ChildName.Text = reader["Child_Name"].ToString();
                                    ChildName.Font.Size = 20;
                                    surname.Text = reader["Child_Surname"].ToString();
                                    surname.Font.Size = 20;
                                    place.Text = reader["Location"].ToString();
                                    place.Font.Size = 14;
                                    genderLabel.Text = reader["Gender"].ToString();
                                    genderLabel.Font.Size = 14;
                                    DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse(reader["Birthday"].ToString());
                                    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
                                    int age = now.Year - birthday.Year;

                                    if (birthday > now.AddYears(-age))
                                    {
                                        age--;
                                    }

                                    Years.Text = age.ToString() + "-years-old";
                                    Years.Font.Size = 14;
                                }

                             connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }

                }
            }
        }

        private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }
```

Comment: You should also specify where / when is the method generating the image id called.

Comment: The image is being generated on page load in a method called chooseImage.

Comment: basically I have done a global variable; 'int childId' and it should stores the result of the method. But I don't know why as I click on the button, it is enetring again in this method and generate another id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Page_Load check if IsPostBack :

```
if(!this.IsPostBack)
     chooseImage();
```

Then you can save your ImageID on Session or ViewState. Or u can use a Hidden TextBox to store the id and retrieve it using Request["hiddenTextBoxId"];

On ASPX Page try to Add a TextBox Hidden :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="txtId" runat="server" />
```

In chooseImage Method put the id in txtId

```
txtId.Text = yourid;
```

And before the Response.Redirect get the id from the textbox :

```
id = txtId.Text;
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the session or the viewstate instead of hiddden fields. You don't need to care about additional fields in your form design. It's easier to maintain. And hidden fields can bring security issues with them. (I'm not telling this is the case here)

Answer (score 2):

When you click that button, a PostBack action will be triggered first before the onclick. 
If you have code in the onload method that may only run once, then you need to wrap it with Page.IsPostBack like here:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    chooseImage();
 }
```

You can use Session to save the value of the childid

```
Session("id") = childId;
```

And then you can use:

```
protected void AboutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = (string) Session("id");
        Response.Redirect("~/ChildDescription.aspx?id=" + id);
    }
```

Comment: I have done that now but now what I am getting is that onclcick the id is 0 all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Call the method that generates the image id only if it's not a postback. Save the id in the ViewState if it's not a part of the postback.

```
  private void Page_Load()
  {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          generateImageId();
      }
  }
```